# B-table tdClass based on adjacent cell value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Example code:

```
   export default {
      data() {
        return {
          fields: [
            { key: "some_key", tdClass: "someClass" },
            { key: "another_key"}
          ],
        },
      methods: {
        someClass(item) {
        if (item > 0) {
          return "table-success"
        }
      }
```

b-table's tdClass recieves an item argument which is cell's value so you can apply style based on that. 
But i need to return style based on adjacent cell's value.

I thought that it's possible to access parent element somehow (row in this case) and access it like row.another_key but i didn't find any info in documentation.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tdClass sends over 3 parameters when called. `(value, key, item)`. So you can use the third parameter to access the other cell.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created() {
      for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){      
        this.items.push({
          id: i + 1,
          email: "test@test.com"
        })
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        fields: [
          { key: 'id' },
          { key: 'email', tdClass: "addTdClass" }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addTdClass(value, key, item) {
        if(item.id % 2)
          return "table-primary"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Examples i saw were using only (item) argument. Thanks.

Comment: @ZavyalovDenis Worries. If you're ever in doubt, the [reference](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#field-definition-reference) sections can be a good place to check.